# How to swap numbers read from a list .txt file? Error "list index out of range"

Tags: python, algorithm, search, swap

What I am trying to do is read from a .txt file containing numbers, then from that list swap 2 of the numbers into different places(index's) in the list. From what I can tell the issue is that the list is being appended, my index's are no longer correct. How can I fix this so I won't get my "list index out of range" error.

*Assignment Task:Your job in this assignment is to create a simple numerical dataset. Collect that data from an external file and then run through the sorting strategy we looked at, swapping.*

```
open_list = open("my_list.txt")
num_list1 = []

for line in open("my_list.txt"):
    line = line.strip()
    num_list1.append(line)
    print(num_list1)             # this is printing my list perfect
                                 # ['15,57,14,33,72,79,26,56,42,40'] is what 
                                 #  prints, which is what im looking for


temp = num_list1[0]              # this is where im running into issues
num_list1[0] = num_list1[2]
num_list1[2] = temp
print(num_list1)
```

Comment: Can you add the full code along with the loops?

Comment: code is above, this is all I have :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to split based on space. Use split() instead of strip(). The strip() method returns a copy of the string with both leading and trailing characters removed (based on the string argument passed). Whereas split() : Split a string into a list where each word is a list item.

open_list = open("my_list.txt")

```
num_list1 = []

for line in open("my_list.txt"):
    line = line.split()
    num_list1.append(line)
    print(num_list1)             # this is printing my list perfect
                                 # ['15,57,14,33,72,79,26,56,42,40'] is what 
                                 #  prints, which is what im looking for


temp = num_list1[0]              # this is where im running into issues
num_list1[0] = num_list1[2]
num_list1[2] = temp
print(num_list1)
```

The full line is getting stored at place [0] between two quotes. Thats why you are getting out of index for [2]. You can test this by printing num_list1[2].

```
print num_list1[2]

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-8965836976ae> in <module>()
     10 #num_list1[2] = temp
     11 print(num_list1)
---> 12 print num_list1[2]

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: how can I retain the index's the numbers were at to then be able to move them around with swapping? thanks!

Comment: or re add index's to them in that case, after I have searched the list and have the numbers from it.

Comment: sorry didnt get what you want to do further?

Comment: I updated the title to be more specific as it was wrong before. I'm trying to swap the 15 and 14, in the list I searched through. The code below that is using the index to change it, but its all set to 0 after searching and appending the list. How could I swap these after reading them?

Comment: Here is what the assignment is asking, I'm on the first step : Swapping. "Your job in this assignment is to create a simple numerical dataset. Collect that data from an external file and then run through the three sorting strategies we looked at; swap, selection sort, insert sort. Be sure to show the final result of each sort."

Comment: so you jsut want to swap the list number 1 and 3. Please follow my code. Use split function to create a list having all numbers. Then you can easily swap the numbers. You will not get index error.

Comment: thank you!! it still didnt work, so I checked out the txt file and the issue was I import a list of numbers with all "," inbetween! Thanks for the help!

Comment: yes that happens "," when you import using strip().